# How to position a button on website using html/css

Tags: html, css

EDIT: The background is simply an image & the section where I place the image is the one I have given

My webpage currently looks like this and I have indicated where I want the button, however I'm very new to coding in general and not sure how to achieve this.

Picture of website page: [image: here]

This is my html code, very simple just needed to add the button

```
<section class="slide kenBurns">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div><p class="ae-2">
            
          </p></div>
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="fix-7-12">
          <!-- <h1 class="ae-1">Messes Make Memories</h1> -->
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img
    src="assets/img/background/flood2.png"
    width="1450"
    height="850"
  ></img>
</section>
```

Comment: The best way to achieve the desired results is to practice. Read about the html and css fundamentals. Read about the <button> element, put it anywhere in your html code, then give it a class: <button class=''myButton''>My button</button>. Then start using css properties to position it wherever you want it in your code. Use position, margin, paddings, etc. Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, try this one code

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
       <style>

       .img { 
       width:100%;
       height: auto;
       top:0;
       left:0;
       position: relative; 
       z-index: 1;
       } 

       .anybutton {
       top:11%;
       left:55%;
       width:100px;
       height:40px;
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 2;
       background: orange; 
       }

      </style>
   </head>

     <body style="text-align:center; margin: 0px;">

       <div class="mycenter" id="">
          <img src="assets/img/background/flood2.png" class="img" id="img" />
          <input type="button" class="anybutton" id="myab" value="Right Here" />
       </div>
       
      </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There 2 types of a buttons
There the real button. Its used to fire an event for JavaScript. It works as in the example below and can by styled like below. You can insert it whereever you want.

```css
button {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="ID">I'm a Button</button>
```

Then there is the Pseudo-Button. Its not a real button. It is just a div box to style a link like a button:

```css
.button {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a href=""><div class="button">I'm a Button</div></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Insert a `<button>` tag in the same parent div which has code for this particular section
   [image: welcome back your portal sally div]

2. Set the css property of the parent element to `position: relative`
3. Set the css property for the `<button>` to `position: absolute`

Lastly, use

```
top : 40px;
right : 100px;
```

for the css property of button tag

**Note:  Change the value of top and right property as per convenience.**

Comment: Depends on what he is trying to achieve. IF he want to fire a JS Event then yes. If he just want to use it as link to open another site or menu, then he should go with a div box.

Comment: I added <button 
                top : 100px;
                left: 10000px;
                
                  >Design</button
                >      this but I can't move the button it always appears in the middle centre

Comment: CS-learner,  thats because, You are question is not clear So I answered, it according to what I understood. 
If you Can share the code in a sandbox. We might able to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.button {
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 42px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: magenta;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 8px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button3 {
  background-color: pink;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button class="button button3">Button 3</button>
```

```
      .button {
            border: none;
            padding: 15px 42px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            color: magenta;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 8px 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            
        }

       .button3 {
            background-color: pink;
            left: 50%;
            position: absolute;
        }
```